# Is it possible to collect data from links and send that information to a database?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, recommendation-engine

I need to build a recommendation system and I want to build it from scratch to practice and get more involved with coding and learning languages. I want to be able to collect user data from a website when user click on links and send that information into a table in the database that would return a set of suggestions according to the links chosen during a given session. Is it even possible to do such thing? For example, say I have a E-store that sells all type of different bikes and gear:

Bikes

- Mountain Bikes
- BMX Bikes
- Triathlon bicycles
- Etc...

Gear

- Mountain helmets
- BMX Helmets
- Triathlon Helmets
- Etc...

Now let's give those categories some ID'S 1,2,3,4,5 & 6 then create a table named `recommendation_system` that would be connected to the `category_table`.

According to the input inserted into `recommendation_system` the `Servlet` will call the appropriate category from the `category_table` and return a set of products.

The system would make precise guesses with user input.

For instance, there are very good probabilities that a user that picks `id(2) BMX Bikes` as first category will be interested to see suggestions from `id(4) BMX Helmets` and so on. Its all about directing the user up to the next same product's "family".

So is it possible to collect those given id's, send them to a database and then display suggestions according to the id that was previously pick? Do I need to use some kind of a form or only handle HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

First you cannot know if a user has clicked on one link. All you know is that during a session, a client has sent a request for a URL, possibly through a link but maybe from its history, directly on address bar, or even through another window of same browser. IMHO a filter could perform that task, or depending of the technology, interceptors (for Spring MVC or Struts2), or aspects on relevant controllers (for any MVC2 solution).

Comment: Basically an easier way to do this would be by using forms input? By that I mean instead of regular URL, use buttons that would send the input into a database...?

Comment: @Boobada : a link and a button are different objects. But seem from server, the only difference is that a button can send any type of request whereas a link can only send GET requests. Anyway I really cannot understand what you want to do.